# Eliminate space before \begin{itemize}

Tags: latex

In Latex, how do I eliminate the space inserted before itemize?

```
\begin{itemize} % produces lots of vertical space
\item ...
\item ...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better-suited on [tex.se].

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115907/how-do-i-remove-white-space-above-itemize-command-in-beamer-using-enumitem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: There are correct answers to this question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86054/157031. (Link shared by PatrickT is also on point)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try `\vspace{-5mm}` before the itemize.

Comment: \vspace is the road to ruin.  You must not fight LaTeX, but rather embrace it.

Comment: yes, but sometimes the fight is too much to handle.

Comment: You mean the embrace is too much to handle, and the fight is easier :-)

Comment: This should be **\vspace{-3.5mm}**.

Comment: @Jason and all: the answer by Paolo below is simple too and much better: *\vspace{-\topsep}*

Comment: vspace is a dirty and quick solution. it should only be used when everything else is ready and only fine-tuning is needed. Otherwise, even adding a paragraph can ruin the whole paragraph.

Comment: This works when using `list` also

Comment: Could it also remove the space after the list?

Answer (score 126):

The way to fix this sort of problem is to redefine the relevant list environment. The `enumitem` package is my favourite way to do this sort of thing; it has many options and parameters that can be varied, either for all lists or for each list individually.

Here's how to do (something like) what it is I think you want:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
```

or

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just as easy as the answer of [Stefano Borini], _but_ this solution works even if there are nested lists. Thank you.

Comment: Even if I set the options to [topsep=0px,partopsep=0px] the vertical space before the list is still there - hence IMHO this answer does not work.

Comment: @Robert, why not use a negative number?  This works for me:  `\begin{enumerate}[topsep=-5px,partopsep=0px] ...`

Comment: @Robert: According to the enumitem docs, the vertical space before and after a list is given by `\parsep + \topsep [+ \partopsep]`, so you either have to set `\topsep` or `\partopsep` to a negative number to compensate for any positive value of `\parsep`.

Comment: You can set list parameters globally: `\setlist[itemize]{topsep=-0.2cm}` (see Global settings in documentation of the enumitem package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Answer (score 67):

- Use `\vspace{-\topsep}` before `\begin{itemize}`
- Use `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}` after `\begin{itemize}`
- And for the space after the list, use `\vspace{-\topsep}` after `\end{itemize}`

```tex
\vspace{-\topsep}
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 1pt}
  \item ...
  \item ...
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-\topsep}
```

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately enumitem is incompatible with beamer, so I like package-independent methods. `topsep` was too aggressive for me, so I went with \vspace{-0.5\topsep}`

Comment: Doing this for every `itemize` is painful...

Comment: Thinking about the same. How would you redifine the environment but get the same results so that you would not need to do this every time?

Answer (score 25):

The cleanest way for you to accomplish this is to use the **enumitem** package (https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). For example,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text and I want to make sure
there is no spacing the different items. 
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\noindent Here is some text and I want to make sure
there is no spacing between this line and the item
list below it.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, if you want to use this setting globally across lists, you can use

```
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
```

However, note that this package does not work well with the **beamer** package which is used to make presentations in Latex.

Comment: As noted (and corrected) elsewhere, the recent versions of enumitem include a [nosep] option which is designed to remove space above and below the list as well as between the items...but it does not do this if you are also using the parskip package. Herbert Voß posted a solution to this on c.t.t. — \setlist{partopsep=-\parskip,parsep=0pt}

Comment: When I add `leftmargin=*` it generated newline again, would it be possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 12):

The "proper" LaTeX ways to do it is to use a package which allows you to specify the spacing you want. There are several such package, and these two pages link to lists of them...

- TeX FAQ entry [How to adjust list spacing](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-complist)
- http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/LatexTips.html

Comment: It is never a bad idea to point at CTAN ( http://www.ctan.org/ ).

Comment: It is, however, generally a bad idea to claim there is a "proper" way to do anything in latex ;).

Answer (score 7):

```
\renewcommand{\@listI}{%
\leftmargin=25pt
\rightmargin=0pt
\labelsep=5pt
\labelwidth=20pt
\itemindent=0pt
\listparindent=0pt
\topsep=0pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\partopsep=0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\parsep=0pt plus 1pt
\itemsep=\parsep}
```

Comment: This reduces a lot of the whitespace around the list, but fails to remove some of the whitespace immediately above and below the list itself.

Comment: This does not work for me... it throws an error unless the code is put inside `\begin{document}`, and even after doing that, it leaves a mysterious `istI` at the beginning of the title page of the PDF.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Answer (score 7):

I'm very happy with the [paralist package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/). Besides adding the option to eliminate the space it also adds other nice things like compact versions of the itemize, enumerate and describe environments.

Comment: Specifically, Fabian is referring to asparaitem, asparaenum and asparadesc and to other things like compactittem, compactenum and compactdesc. aspara does create a new paragraph still. This is still slightly annoying if you're putting them in a table without a preceding paragraph, as I am, but I suspect that there's a less ugly hack to fix this.